# Struts controller/porccessor monitoring/log utility

Tags: struts, monitoring

I'm looking for some kind of monitoring tool to visualize/log all internal struts forwards together with all http headers, parameters, request and session attributes values.
The intend is to understand the full flow of certain request in struts 1.x application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK nothing like that exists out-of-the-box (particularly showing all request/etc. values, which could be huge). Your best bet might be to turn up logging to debug, and likely to create a custom request processor that dumps the information you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MaintainJ to monitor all calls and methods in java web application... And in firefox install 'firebug' run it select net tag... Under this tag you can see every server call and response of that call...
 Chrome too have this feature...

Comment: MaintainJ looks like what I'm after..Thanks